Unity Adressables: sprites inside texture not working inside build (2022.03.20f1)
We are trying to load sprites from a texture using Unity Adressables. The texture is from type "Sprite (2D and UI)". Before the build, we always made a clean Adressable Groups build, by clearing the cache.
The code to load the texture is the following:
public async void LoadSprite(String spritePath)
{
     AsyncOperationHandle<Sprite[]> spritesHandle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<Sprite[]>(spritePath);
     await spritesHandle.Task;

     if (spritesHandle.Status == AsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded)
     {
          Sprite[] sprites = spritesHandle.Result;
          // rest of code...
     }
}

The code works perfectly fine inside the Unity Editor. However, it doesn't work inside the build. It just tells that the array "sprites" is always null.
I tried to load the texture as a Texture2D using the method from above and assign it to an image component, which worked. It displayed the texture perfectly fine in the build.
We tried looping through the result and adding it manually to a list. Somehow the objects inside the result are always 0, but the texture can be displayed fine. Length of the result is also always 0.
So somehow the sprites inside the texture get lost somewhere.
